# Best form to find an image among a hundred heavy PSD files?

Tags: windows-vista, images, adobe-photoshop

So my former co-worker left us with more or less a hundred of large, badly named Photoshop files.

I want to find a particular image but opening each file is becoming tedious, and Vista is not able to preview PSD files.

Do you have any ideas on how can I find my image?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After starting photoshop, use `File > Browse..` and navigate to the folder in question. The inbuilt Photoshop browser has thumbnail previews of files.

Answer (score 2):

[Faststone Image Viewer](http://www.faststone.org/FSViewerDownload.htm) can open **.psd** files just like it opens **.jpeg** files.

more links at my post [here](https://superuser.com/questions/41670/best-preferred-software-for-photography/43874#43874).

Comment: well, does it have a Browse option? I'm not simply looking for something that can open psd files.

Comment: yes, faststone has a superb browser interface. do check it out. thats what I use for sifting through my .psd files.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at installing a [preview handler for PSD files](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista/PhotoshopPreviewHandler.aspx) in vista. (not tested) After this use the arrow keys on the keyboard to browse forwards and backwards through the list of files this should speed things up considerably.

Comment: useful but the Browse option in Photoshop is faster.

Answer (score 1):

[IrfanView](http://www.irfanview.com/) works quite well if you want to browse them full size, rather than as thumbnails.

Comment: But IrfanView only works with psd files that are saved with the compability option checked. Or whatever it was called.. at least I think that was the case. Unless they have fixed it in later versions?